# compose key for us international layout not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, internationalization

After my upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 my compose key is not working as it did before anymore.

This is my input configuration:

```
setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
variant:    intl
options:    compose:ralt
```

I set my keyboard with `setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl`.

But pressing e.g. right-alt + q does not produce ä.
I noticed there are other configurations now, e.g. right-alt + " + a produces ä.

I'm a bit confused why this suddenly changed. Am I using the wrong layout?

Comment: What if you change the keyboard layout in the Settings?

Comment: I tried changing the settings with the `gnome-tweak-tool` and disabled the compose key, but that did not seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *English (US, intl., with dead keys)* keyboard layout uses <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> by default as the key to access 3rd and 4th level symbols. That way you can for instance press <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to type **ä**.

But since you defined <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> to serve as the compose key, you override its function as the 3rd level key.

So maybe you don't need a compose key. Or maybe you should define some other key but <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> as the compose key.